# Can we use an LQG controller if the system is not observable?

Tags: control-theory, estimation, optimal-control, parameter-estimation, kalman-filter

I understand an LQG controller is essentially an LQE + LQR. So, if I understand properly, we basically apply the gain estimated from LQR to our state estimate from LQE (e.g., a Kalman filter).

Does LQG require the system to be observable (i.e., bounded error growth)? The observability of the systems states is not a requirement of the Kalman filter.

Comment: Detectability is enough for LQE and stabilizability is enough for LQR.

Comment: So, LQG requires stabilizability and detectability? Do you a reference I can find with more detail?